# Import options for simple products CSV - pros vs cons (Magento 2.2.8)

Tags: magento2, import-products

Currently I'm using magento 2.2.8 and so far I know about 3 main options to import simple products (**using csv file**).

**a) csv import** (Magento seems quite slow on this end) and only allows batches of about 400 products locally (on live server, only 100). This is the option I've already tried.

**b) Using rest.** Have to do some coding to get it working, as well as get acquainted with it.

**c) Magento API.** Have to do some coding to get it working, as well as get acquainted with it.

My prefered way would be to use direct sql queries + some php, but seems that database structure is a little bit convoluted.

- On speed: Which method is faster? Would have a go on coding if it proves worthy on b or c
- On batch size: Which method allows more products "per batch"?
- Are there other methods I've not considered?

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, but don't have the budget (**0 budget**) for something like fire and bear (which according to their site works wonders, but is out of question here).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you like to experiment you can try this tool
https://m2if.com/

> Compatible with Magento 2 Community and Commerce Edition!
>
> The Magento 2 Import Framework M2IF comes with a set of powerful
>   components, that support you to build high performance, rock solid and
>   easy to use import services 100 % compatible with the default Magento
>   2 CSV format

but for any heavy imports you need to increase apache/php/mysql limits and timeouts.